# Run LUA with torch7 on LINUX server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lua, torch

I am trying to run a LUA script on my ubuntu server but getting the following error:

> ```
> >     lua: train.lua:6: module 'torch' not found:
> >             no field package.preload['torch']
> >             no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.4/torch.lua'
> >             no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.4/torch/init.lua'
> >             no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/torch.lua'
> >             no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/torch/init.lua'
> >             no file './torch.lua'
> >             no file './torch/init.lua'
> >             no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/torch.so'
> >             no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/loadall.so'
> >             no file './torch.so'
> >     stack traceback:
> >             [C]: in function 'require'
> >             train.lua:6: in main chunk
> >             [C]: in ?
> ```

Torch7 is installed on the system. How do I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure Torch is installed? Where is it installed to?

Comment: iirc you don't require `torch` from normal Lua but run `th` instead